# while loops and possible if statements

Tags: python

I need to write a function that will list n amount of numbers that are divisible by m. So if I list the function divisibility(10,2) it will list the first 10 numbers divisible by 2. This is in Python 3. Any basic structures that I can manipulate would be helpful. Brand new programmer, so all insight will much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to show some effort toward solving the problem before the community will be willing to help. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Write a function? That function already exists, and it's called `range()`.

Answer (score 1):

Divisible just means “a multiple of”

```
divisible_by = 2
number_of_numbers_you_want = 10

for i in range(number_of_numbers_you_want):
    print(i*divisible_by)
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I appreciate it!

Comment: don't forget to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: This is needlessly complex.

Comment: complex in what way? Seems pretty simple and straightforward to me

Answer (score 1):

Another way of saying "divisible by" is "multiple of". To put if simply, you have to write a program to output the first 10 multiples of 2. You can use range() function for this.

The range function can take 3 inputs. range(x, y, z)
x is starting index (inclusive)
y is ending index (exclusive)
z is stepping

```
def divisibility(n, m):  
    for i in range(0, (n * m) + 1, m):  
        print(i)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: This is just a wrapper around `range()`.